# How to create a partition without unmounting?

Tags: boot, partitioning

As you can guess, I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Kali. 
But the thing is that i don't have a spare ubuntu iso(which would allow me to live boot ubuntu and then create a partition using g parted or any other app since my hd remains unmounted). So, it would be very awesome if anyone could provide me a way to create a new partition without unmounting it.. TIA

Comment: Give more info, what distro your currently using? Do you have iso for kali? The safest way to go would be to make a live cd with _gparted_ on it

Comment: http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Comment: To install Ubuntu, you're going to need to make a Ubuntu Live DVD or USB flash key, using the .ISO file that you downloaded. Once made, you can boot to it and manually run gparted to create your desired partitions, or just run the installer to auto/manually create the desired partitions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a new partition you will have to shrink one and create space for the new one. You can't shrink a mounted partition or unmount a partition of a running system. That's where you need a live ubuntu, either on a CD or simply on a USB-stick.

Comment: It can be done on windows 10. I wonder why it cant be done on Linux.