# partitioning - How to create new partition through unused size without livecd

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, root

I do not have any drives, so I have to do without anything. What should I do?
[image]

Comment: With gparted itself you can resize.

Comment: It does not allow. Also I am asking how to create a partition?

Comment: First you need to unmount the drive and then resize. Show the photo of the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a partition without unmounting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899789/how-to-create-a-partition-without-unmounting)

Comment: What you are asking is like how to change the tire of my car while I am driving the car. You have to stop driving the car first.

Comment: @user68186 this is possible on windows 10. I wonder why linux doesn't allow this.

Comment: I know it is possible in Windows. I also know you can change an oar in a rowboat while the boat is moving. Other things are possible in Linux but not in Windows. This site is not for asking "why?" and "why not?". Please see the site [help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for what kind of questions are are suitable for this site.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to shrink partition and make a new partition?  If for back ups might want to see about getting an external drive, in case your drive dies.  Would probably need an USB drive if you want to install another OS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done on linux. You will need live boot, or install another OS, in another partition. And from the other OS, do the wanted.